# Adding a UIImageView as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainWallViewController.h"
@interface MainWallViewController ()
{
   onClickViewController *on;
}
@end


@implementation MainWallViewController
- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender
{
    on = [[onClickViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"onClickViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:on.view];
    NSLog(@"abcdefghijk");
}

@end
```

`onClickViewController` contains an image and a button.
Below screen shot will show you that

[image: screen shot]

When `onClickViewController.view` appears, only the new button is displayed but the image does not show up!!
Please help!!

Comment: If you go to the onClickViewController.xib file, are you sure the image is there? Can you upload a screenshot of what it looks like on Interface Builder?

Comment: yea sure...i'm uploading...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Se4qO.jpg

Comment: try [RNBlurModalView](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView).

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:onClickViewController animated:YES]; and [self.navigationController presentViewController: onClickViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; are other options to show your view.

Answer (score 0):

add `[on loadView]` after `initWithNib` and be sure to call `[super viewWillAppear:animated] on viewWillAppear.`

Answer (score 0):

Can u please check with the constraint and also check bounds and frame in **viewDidAppear()** delegate method. better Print the Frame in **NSLog()** in view did appear method.